# Vertical Rebar (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I was wondering if it was possible to make a Rebar that goes vertically instead of controls horizontally? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes :)

Google for CCS_VERT style as keyword (this one makes toolbars vertical).